# adjusting devices according to screensize

Tags: android

I don't know if such devices really exist but, considering that they could, consider the following two devices:

[image: devices]

I was trying to adjust size of widgets giving them a certain percentage of width, height etc, and since android devices are categorized as x, xhpi, xxhdpi etc, I thought dpi would be a good way to adjust their size but as you can see above this isn't the case.

An example case is: say if the device is small then I want a menu bar to take half of the screen and if it is large I'd want it to take only one third.

What would be a better way to adjust these widgets?

EDIT: If I use ConstraintLayout some of the buttons would have to be hardcoded with their size, but I want the buttons to get slightly bigger/smaller according to the screen sizes.

Comment: You can use ConstraintLayout would be better solution for percentage vice screen render

Comment: some of the buttons would have to be hardcoded with their size, but I want the buttons to get slightly bigger/smaller according to the screen sizes

Comment: have you read https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your app app launch Find display's width and height.

Using this code, you can get the runtime display's width & height:

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
```

According to your height and width `onCreate` method to set component programmatically Like Button, Textview and others.

Answer (score 1):

First, for your requirement of being able to use percentages, you can utilize a ConstraintLayout. I'd recommend the [official training documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout) to start. ConstraintLayout is relatively new (first release Feb 2017) so there aren't as many third party tutorials that are updated - but there should be enough info out to answer any questions you have to start.

Here's a short example:

```
<MenuBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.5" />
```

For the second part of your question, you can provide alternate resources with different config qualifiers like `xxhdpi` like you mentioned above. More information on that [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#AlternativeResources). To store a float value as a dimen in both the device form factors you want you'd declare in dimen.xml in `res/values-[config_qualifiers]`.

```
<item name="bottom_menu_bar_height_percent" type="dimen" format="float">0.3</item>
```

Referencing from xml

```
<MenuBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_constraintHeight_percent=
    "@dimen/bottom_menu_bar_height_percent" />
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: "resource bucket" could you please explain me what does this mean? I mean, I haven't mentioned it anywhere in my question.

Comment: @juztcode Sure! I edited the answer to provide some clarification and extra docs :)